# Take the average of each row of pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to take the average of each row of `kirp_df`, such that it returns the average for each row indices. My code returned NaN for each row despite removing NA.

```
kirp_df = df.loc[:, df.loc["subtype"] == "KIRP"][:-2].dropna()
kirp_df.mean(axis=1)
```

Traceback:

```
/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/ipykernel_launcher.py:1: FutureWarning: Dropping of nuisance columns in DataFrame reductions (with 'numeric_only=None') is deprecated; in a future version this will raise TypeError.  Select only valid columns before calling the reduction.
  """Entry point for launching an IPython kernel.
cg00000029   NaN
cg00000165   NaN
cg00000236   NaN
cg00000289   NaN
cg00000292   NaN
              ..
cg09560658   NaN
cg09560763   NaN
cg09560811   NaN
cg09560911   NaN
cg09560953   NaN
Length: 142513, dtype: float64
```

#####################################################
Data:

`kirp_df.iloc[1:10,1:10].to_dict()`

```
{'TCGA-2Z-A9J1-01A': {'cg00000165': 0.0807243779293262,
  'cg00000236': 0.867305510246114,
  'cg00000289': 0.70680600651273,
  'cg00000292': 0.217862460492399,
  'cg00000321': 0.169408257004071,
  'cg00000363': 0.173115013795265,
  'cg00000622': 0.0108902025634162,
  'cg00000658': 0.813866558997356,
  'cg00000721': 0.938576461648791},
 'TCGA-2Z-A9J2-01A': {'cg00000165': 0.437447195378987,
  'cg00000236': 0.898927359292032,
  'cg00000289': 0.758108726247342,
  'cg00000292': 0.868604834806246,
  'cg00000321': 0.577744851436078,
  'cg00000363': 0.567241575633452,
  'cg00000622': 0.0122683781097633,
  'cg00000658': 0.881366097769717,
  'cg00000721': 0.936584647488041},
 'TCGA-2Z-A9J3-01A': {'cg00000165': 0.0642332527783939,
  'cg00000236': 0.917290578229414,
  'cg00000289': 0.675537604266578,
  'cg00000292': 0.543087013952312,
  'cg00000321': 0.85044433769089,
  'cg00000363': 0.470810530680518,
  'cg00000622': 0.0125681212511168,
  'cg00000658': 0.870735609192125,
  'cg00000721': 0.956356142020249},
 'TCGA-2Z-A9J5-01A': {'cg00000165': 0.126118535539944,
  'cg00000236': 0.928017823091886,
  'cg00000289': 0.677846427070521,
  'cg00000292': 0.850473788130218,
  'cg00000321': 0.44473521937132,
  'cg00000363': 0.204529155293748,
  'cg00000622': 0.0122330126903632,
  'cg00000658': 0.906102120405464,
  'cg00000721': 0.938145301973259},
 'TCGA-2Z-A9J6-01A': {'cg00000165': 0.112151024422993,
  'cg00000236': 0.881981171862823,
  'cg00000289': 0.695606438687072,
  'cg00000292': 0.846718372472362,
  'cg00000321': 0.757733166615607,
  'cg00000363': 0.172813874013867,
  'cg00000622': 0.0124341091006015,
  'cg00000658': 0.875702288602203,
  'cg00000721': 0.949350493096875},
 'TCGA-2Z-A9J7-01A': {'cg00000165': 0.559088973726113,
  'cg00000236': 0.901815470518336,
  'cg00000289': 0.805920947304252,
  'cg00000292': 0.640825631457383,
  'cg00000321': 0.621308654785173,
  'cg00000363': 0.0722588860930127,
  'cg00000622': 0.0100408106849315,
  'cg00000658': 0.856460615834933,
  'cg00000721': 0.945808996938907},
 'TCGA-2Z-A9J8-01A': {'cg00000165': 0.0993225901397478,
  'cg00000236': 0.889537978677822,
  'cg00000289': 0.691597185851671,
  'cg00000292': 0.813122933295151,
  'cg00000321': 0.710712761159508,
  'cg00000363': 0.579117830986195,
  'cg00000622': 0.0145401029579807,
  'cg00000658': 0.833725365229449,
  'cg00000721': 0.930732020027994},
 'TCGA-2Z-A9J9-01A': {'cg00000165': 0.0871408483321741,
  'cg00000236': 0.879968490399937,
  'cg00000289': 0.549769911227498,
  'cg00000292': 0.283154379541085,
  'cg00000321': 0.48310833426734,
  'cg00000363': 0.0694935460463862,
  'cg00000622': 0.0126142511240202,
  'cg00000658': 0.885015967416138,
  'cg00000721': 0.933393915741336},
 'TCGA-2Z-A9JD-01A': {'cg00000165': 0.0954830889751504,
  'cg00000236': 0.877101253439035,
  'cg00000289': 0.700443114118019,
  'cg00000292': 0.645773476077286,
  'cg00000321': 0.446177255074733,
  'cg00000363': 0.389318735766059,
  'cg00000622': 0.0155373951272166,
  'cg00000658': 0.882984941909313,
  'cg00000721': 0.92890097781832}}
```

Example output:

```
cg00000165    0.184634
cg00000236    0.893550
cg00000289    0.695737
cg00000292    0.634403
cg00000321    0.562375
cg00000363    0.299855
cg00000622    0.012570
cg00000658    0.867329
cg00000721    0.939761
```

Comment: `df.mean(axis=1)`? this works fine with your example, if you have non-numeric columns: `df.select_dtypes('number').mean(axis=1)`

Comment: @mozway my example was probably not good. I could compute the mean for the example but not for the entire dataframe. I tried `select_dtypes('number')` but it still return NaN.

Comment: Then please, be explicit. The warning you got is not reproducible with the provided code and example. This is usually due to having non-numeric columns